# Is it possible to create database view programmatically?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I know one can create Database Views in DDIC, but is it possible to define a Database View directly with ABAP?

Comment: ...why? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function modules `DDIF_VIEW_PUT` for creation and `DDIF_VIEW_ACTIVATE` for activation of view. But you should specify all table parameters carefully, as incorrect parameters could result in failure of creation.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is impossible with ABAP. You would have to debug what is under the hood in the SAP ABAP Code when you create your view in `SE11`.

I know there is a possibility of creating a transparent table on the fly in ABAP, so I believe there is a possibility of creating a view as well. Of course such an object would have to be assigned to `$TMP` package and not be transportable.